# Using a sig_atomic_t flag together with blocking calls

Tags: c, signals, posix

Say I have a flag to indicate an exit condition that I with to enable with a signal. Then I can attach the following handler to SIGUSR1 for instance.

```
volatile sig_atomic_t finished = 0;

void catch_signal(int sig)
{
  finished = 1;
}
```

I then use the flag to determine when a particular loop should end. In this particular case I have a thread running (but I believe my problem applies without threads also, so don't focus on that part).

```
void *thread_routine(void *arg)
{
  while (!finished) {
    /* What if the signal happens here? */
    if ((clientfd = accept(sockfd, &remote_addr, &addr_size)) == -1) {
      if (errno == EINTR)
        continue;
      /* Error handling */
    }

    handle_client(clientfd);
  }
}
```

This loop is supposed to continue to run until I raise my SIGUSR1 signal. When it receives the signal I want it to stop gracefully as soon as possible. Since I have a blocking accept call I don't have the loop spinning around wasting CPU cycles, which is good, and the signal can at any moment interrupt the blocking accept and cause the loop to terminate.

The problem is, as shown in the comment in the code, that the signal could be delivered right after the while condition but before the accept call. Then the signal handler will set `finished` to true, but after the execution resumes, `accept` will be called and block indefinitely. How can I avoid this condition and make sure that I always will be able to terminate the loop with my signal?

Assuming I still want to use a signal to control this, I can think of two possible solutions. The first one is to turn on some alarm that re-raises a signal after a while if the signal was missed the first time. The second one is to put a timeout on the socket so that accept returns after some amount time so that the flag can be examined again. But these solutions are more like workarounds (especially since I change the blocking behaviour of accept in my second solution) and if there is some cleaner and more straightforward solution I'd like to use that instead.

Comment: Instead of handling the whole loop-accept in multiple thread (and as `accept` itself it not thread-safe, think about what will happen if one threads `accept` is preempted in the middle by another thread who also does `accept`), do it in the "main" thread and create a new thread after calling `accept` and pass the new socket to it.

Comment: There will be only one instance of this thread. The call to `handle_client` OTOH can hand over work to other threads. So even though this is not the "main" thread it would work almost like it. Maybe what I really should do here is to cancel the thread. But if this weren't a thread I couldn't do that, so I still wonder how to do it with a signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Self-Pipe Trick](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/altio/self_pipe.c.html) can be used in such cases.
You open a pipe  and use `select` to wait both on the pipefd and sockfd. The handler writes a char to the pipe.  After the select, checking  fd  set helps you determine if you can go for accept or not.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is over a year old, now, but `pselect()` was designed exactly for this type of situation. You can provide `pselect()` (and `select()` generally) with file descriptors of listening sockets, and those functions will return when there is an `accept()`able connection available.

The general approach is you block all relevant signals, and then call `pselect()` with a signal mask to unblock them. `pselect()` will atomically:

1. Unblock the signal(s)
2. Call `accept()`
3. Block the signal(s) again when `accept()` returns

so you can essentially guarantee that the only time that signal will actually be delivered and handled is when `pselect()` is running, and you don't have to worry about it being caught after you check `finished` but before you call `accept()`. In other words, you make sure that whenever that signal is delivered, it'll always interrupt `pselect()` and set `errno` to `EINTR`, so that's the only place you have to check for it.